# set specific border for each segment

Tags: swift, border, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to set a specific border color for selected segment and set a diffrence border color for each others. Here an example that I want to do it.

[image]

But I don't know how can I do it.

Comment: Are you wanting the selected segment to be a unique color? iOS 13 introduced a way to do this.

Comment: Yes I wanna exactly that, but my app should be run on ios 10

Comment: the second section of my answer should do that for you. Give it a try and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is make use of `UISegmentedControl`'s `selectedSegmentTintColor`. Setting this will make the selected segment a different color from all other segments.

You can also get the `UISegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex` and use this index to manually change the color of the selected segment's border. The way you would do this is:

```swift
@IBAction func segmentedControlValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    let selectedIndex = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
    segmentedControl.subviews[selectedIndex].layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
}
```